# is it possible to get a Hardware Id (should be unique for all devices) from device (mobile, tablets and laptops)for a website in ASP.NET core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I want to get Hardware Id from the device using website login. the Hardware Id should be Unique for all the devices.i am using MVC Asp.Net. if this is possible how ? i have previously tried using Reactjs but Not get any solution for the problem.

Comment: For multiple reasons, many relating to security and/or privacy, no you cannot.

Answer (score 0):

in SEO, using GCP, you can get a statistic of user devices visiting your web application. But you are not going to get any user device's IP address because of obvious security and privacy reasons. Not sure how is your question related to .NET.

Comment: If you have to say something that is not an answer, please post a comment instead.

Comment: Did you read the OP question? He was asking for device if in .Net. I provide him how he could get an idea on the statistics of users on his web app. How is that not related to his question?

Comment: Well, it's not even coherent. What do you mean by "in SEO"? Also, how can websites like https://whatismyipaddress.com/ show your ip without asking for any permission if it's "not possible"?

Comment: Because you are looking at your own IP address not another person IP like OP was referring to. So you wouldnt need permission for that. Also SEO stands for search Engine Optimization.

Comment: I know what SEO stands for, but the sentence isn't coherent either. And it's my own ip, but visible on a website that's not my own, so they can indeed see what my ip is without permission. Anything that's shown on the website, they can send back to the server. Anyway, no point in continuing this conversation, you need to learn the basics of websites first.